# how to loop through each column in a row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, helper

I got the dataframe like this

[image]

How can I use pandas to loops all column in a rows and get the result like this

```
=(Frank,Math,8.5,History,9.7,Biology,0.0,Physis,5.4)
=(Mary,Math,0.0,History,2.5,Biology,0.0,Physis,0.0)
........
```

Thanks you for all your helping

Comment: Please provide your example data as text, not as an image and the output you actually expect, not a part of something like it. You are expected to show your own efforts to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is not clear but try:

```
def format_row(row):
    marks = ','.join([f"{i},{v}" for i, v in row.items()])
    return f"=({row.name},{marks})"
print('\n'.join(df.apply(format_row, axis=1)))

# Output:
=(Franck,Math,8.5,History,9.7)
=(Mary,Math,0.0,History,2.5)
```

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Math': {'Franck': 8.5, 'Mary': 0.0},
                   'History': {'Franck': 9.7, 'Mary': 2.5}})
print(df)

# Output:
        Math  History
Franck   8.5      9.7
Mary     0.0      2.5
```

Comment: Thanks you bro :D